# LinkedIn - Is it possible to post into my app's user's groups?

Tags: c#, share, linkedin-api

I want to be able to automatically (after getting access tokens) choose a group amongst the groups of the user and post a link and text to them.

I've tried a few C# APIs for linked in but at the time a few months back I didn't see an option to do so.

Is it possible to even do so? The word 'group' does not even exist in LinkedIn REST Share API documentation. if it's possible, any recommended LinkedIN APIs to use for C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Starting on May 12, 2015, we will be limiting the open APIs to only support the following uses"

https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

They no longer expose group API publicly, you have to partner them first, I wish this information was more widely spread though.